# Powershell to MySQL insert multiple returned rows into database

Tags: mysql, .net, powershell, insert

I have a powershell script that I use for logon discovery purposes. The one liner is:

```
$events = get-eventlog -log system -computername '.' |
where-object {(($_.EventID -like "*7001*") -or ($_.EventID -like "*7002*"))} |
select-object replacementstrings, machinename, timegenerated
```

This returns 'remote computer' logon details that I need to do a SID lookup in another table. The problem is I CANNOT get the MySQL insert statement to loop through results. It will insert 1 row from the above $events var. When I echo $events out in the loop It walks through the returned results just as you would assume...I looked everywhere for someone who talks about inserting multiple rows with powershell, but found (0) results in my hunt. I currently am using the .net connector for mySQL and would like to make that work if possible to avoid learning pains, but almost think it is time for something new. below is my code -minus the credential vars:

```
# MySQL Connection string #
function Connect-MySQL([string]$user,[string]$pass,[string]$MySQLHost, [string]$database) { 

    # Load MySQL .NET Connector Objects 
            [void] [system.reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data") 

                $connStr = "server=" + $MySQLHost + ";port=3306;uid=" + $user + ";pwd=" + $pass + ";database="+$database+";Pooling=FALSE" 
                $conn = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection($connStr) 
                $conn.Open() 
                return $conn 
                } 

                # Close Conn
                function Disconnect-MySQL($conn) {
                $conn.Close()
                }


# MySQL Connection Vars #
$user = '' 
$pass = ''
$database = '' 
$MySQLHost = '' 

$conn = Connect-MySQL $user $pass $MySQLHost $database

                function Execute-MySQLNonQuery($conn, [string]$query) { 
                $command = $conn.CreateCommand()                  
                $command.CommandText = $query                     
                $RowsInserted = $command.ExecuteNonQuery()       
                $command.Dispose()                                

                if ($RowsInserted) { 
                    return $RowInserted 
                    } else { 
                    return $false 
                    } 
                    } 
foreach($event in $events){
$sid = $event.replacementstrings[1]
$time = $event.timegenerated
$id = $event.machinename
$query = "INSERT INTO info.ewarp_testing (data1,data2,data3) VALUES ('$sid',     '$time','$id')"
$Rows = Execute-MySQLNonQuery $conn $query
}
```

I have asked around but have not got any answers for this issue. Certainly I cannot be the only one that needs to insert an entireoutput from powershell into a mysql db? :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to let everyone know- I did not find a .NET solution for this. We are multithreading 600 instances of powershell on a server so the scope of this question was a bit rich I suppose. I ended up dropping a csv file from powershell and passing a hostname var in the name of the file. Then I called a python script to consume the csv and and input into mysql and then delete the file. This proved much easier than trying to tanlge with .NET- at least for me....cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. I sped it up a little bit by changing the scope of your `$conn` variable and replaced `Get-EventLog` with `Get-WinEvent`. I *believe* your problem was the `$command.Dispose()` line but I can't test it right now.  Give this a shot.

Is this doesn't work you may want to look into casting `$side`, `$time` and `$Id` to strings by appending `[string]` before each.

```
# MySQL Connection string #
function Connect-MySQL([string]$user, [string]$pass, [string]$MySQLHost, [string]$database)
{
    # Load MySQL .NET Connector Objects 
    [void][system.reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")

    $connStr = "server=" + $MySQLHost + ";port=3306;uid=" + $user + ";pwd=" + $pass + ";database=" + $database + ";Pooling=FALSE"
    $conn = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection($connStr)
    $conn.Open()
    return $conn
}

# Close Conn
function Disconnect-MySQL()
{
    $conn.Close()
}

# MySQL Connection Vars #
$user = ''
$pass = ''
$database = ''
$MySQLHost = ''

$script:conn = Connect-MySQL $user $pass $MySQLHost $database

function Execute-MySQLNonQuery([string]$query)
{
    $command = $conn.CreateCommand()
    $command.CommandText = $query
    $RowsInserted = $command.ExecuteNonQuery()

    if ($RowsInserted)
    {
        return $RowInserted
    }
    else
    {
        return $false
    }
}

$events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ LogName = 'System'; ID = 7001, 7002 } | select replacementstrings, machinename, timegenerated

foreach ($event in $events)
{
    $sid = $event.replacementstrings[1]
    $time = $event.timegenerated
    $id = $event.machinename
    $query = "INSERT INTO info.ewarp_testing (data1,data2,data3) VALUES ('$sid','$time','$id')"
    $Rows = Execute-MySQLNonQuery $query
}
```

Comment: adbertram: I tried the above and did not get the result I needed. I choose get-eventlog instead of winevent because I need the attribution of the SID identifier. Winevent returns a partial SID (I also tried -expandproperty with no luck). I stripped off the dispose() command and Im still getting the same result of one row inserted into the mysql database.

Comment: If you put Write-Host $query right below your $query definition line does it should each INSERT line you're expecting?

Comment: I did write-host $query and got my results in this format: INSERT INTO followed by my correct values. And it called each one out with a seperate insert statement. I get all 15 log entries I need, but it still only inserts one. Is this something to do with the INSERT syntax?

Comment: I'm no MySQL expert. That should work.  You could look at using this method instead. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html